# '[json.exception.type_error.302] type must be number, but is string'

Tags: c++, json

```
{
  "name": "hw-cpp",
  "description": "tsa parameters",
  "policy_type_id": 20008,
  "create_schema": {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "threshold": {
        "type": "integer",
        "default": 0
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

Above is my JSON.
I'm using JSON.

I try this code

```
payload = json::parse(mbuf.payload);
```

using c++ with **nlohmann** library

Any help?

Comment: Dunno, works for me without any problems. [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please

Comment: thats the whole code, what do u mean mcve?

Comment: To help you, people need a whole C++ source code they can copy-paste into an IDE, compile, run and debug. For example, the first line could be `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`, then next line could be `int main()`, and so on. Also, that whole source code needs to be short, while still exhibiting the problem you describe. The MCVE stands for minimal, complete and verifiable example, and there is a help page shortly describing how to create one, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, we cannot compile your C++ code: where is `int main()`?